# implement interface in java

Tags: java, file, exception, interface

I am using an interface in java. I want to put the data in a file and when i compile the program appear this error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Teatro; local class incompatible: stream classdesc      serialVersionUID = -8638492166751354209, local class serialVersionUID = 8721614984870769537
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at CarteleraProg.main(CarteleraProg.java:107)
```

> error Teatro; local class incompatible: stream classdesc
>   serialVersionUID = -8638492166751354209, local class serialVersionUID
>   = 8721614984870769537

```
 public interface Playable {

public void ImprimirDatos();

 }

 public void ImprimirDatos(){
System.out.println ("TITULO TEATRO: " + getTitulo());
System.out.println ("DIRECTOR: " + getDirector());
System.out.println ("ESCENOGRAFO: " + getEsceno() );
System.out.println ("FECHA: " + getFecha());
   }
```

What can i do to solve that?

Thank you very much

Comment: of course! what class do you need?

Comment: Preferably both the interface and the class that implements it.

Comment: public interface Playable {
 
 public void ImprimirDatos();

}

Comment: Preferably edit it into the question in a readable manner.

Comment: public void ImprimirDatos(){
  System.out.println ("TITULO PELICULA: " + getTitulo());
  System.out.println ("DIRECTOR: " + getDirector());
  System.out.println ("ACTOR PRINCIPAL: " + getActor() );
  System.out.println ("FECHA: " + getFecha());
 }

Comment: It seems that the problem is with you operating with different `Serial Versions` of the class.

Comment: This is not a compilation error but `run-time exception`. Do you get compilation error(s) as well?

Comment: I have edit the question and i have put the code of the interface and the function

Answer (score 1):

You (or the library you use) have changed the class `Teatro` to create another serial format (changed/added/removed a member, changed the superclass, ...) **after** you have written an object of class `Teatro` to a stream.

If you are really sure, use a fixed id:

```
public class Teatro implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8638492166751354209L;

  ...
}
```

Comment: how do you take the number of the serialVersionUID?